# Using TimePicker with default time (predefined time disables timepicker)

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have 3 elements in my form that require a date/time picker. For each element, there is a different default time that i need applied.

If i set the default time in the config / format option, then the ability to select the time disappears from the datepicker. If i enter a valid time format in the option, i am then able to use the timepicker, but selecting a new date also sets the value of the element to the current time:

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker_earliest').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en-gb',
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY 16:00',
            extraFormats: ['DD/MM/YYYY H:MM']
        });
    });
```

What i would like to achieve is if no time is selected, then a default time is used. If a new time is selected using the time picker, then this is used. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event to set custom time when the user selects a day.

The event receives `date` and `oldDate` as parameters and you can use moment's setters ([`hour`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/), [`minute`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/)) on them to update picker time according your needs.

You can change datetimepicker's date using [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) function.

Here a working example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker_earliest').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'en-gb',
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
  extraFormats: ['DD/MM/YYYY H:mm']
}).on('dp.change', function(e){
  if( !e.oldDate || !e.date.isSame(e.oldDate, 'day')){
    e.date.hour(16).minute(0);
    $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_earliest">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```